# Refreshing image in attribute form based on classifier using QGIS

Tags: qgis, html, geopackage, widget, photos

We have two tables:

- **road_signs** (road sign points).
- **lut_road_signs** (classifier of road signs), this table has a column sing_img (blob) in which the image of road signs is written in png format.

How to make it so that when editing the table road_signs (**in Attribute Form**) the image of the road sign is redrawn when choosing a different sign from the classifier?

[image: before change]

[image: after change]

GeoPackage with data and project can be downloaded from this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WuO-IFdzE3B7S-_DVevKfyOWVUUhmvGA/view?usp=sharing, inside in geopackage we can find project and open it and see how to realise viewing image stored in blob database on dialog forms. Project name: **road_sign_prj_1**:
[image]